# Typescript check whether a type is tuple or array

Tags: typescript

```
type A = [1, 2, 3]
type B = (1|2|3)[]

type IsTuple<T> = ???

type C = IsTuple<A> // true
type D = IsTuple<B> // false
```

I am looking for a way to tell tuple and array type apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update, I figured out the answer, by checking the length

```
type A = [1, 2, 3]
type B = (1|2|3)[]

type C = A['length'] //3
type D = B['length'] // number
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBGANFATBgzAXQChRIoAhBKAChQB9MacBKJQo8aAYQpiQHIAbCADsA5sAAWvPFAD0MnGxIARCqT6DREqbJlQhAVwC2AIwgAnAkA)

Answer (score 2):

This is the method I always use:

```
type IsTuple<T> = T extends [any, ...any] ? true : false
```

We can basically check if there are individual elements inside the tuple.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=4&ssc=57&pln=4&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDaBGANFATBgzAXQFgAoUSKAIQSgAoUAfTOnASiUKONOgEkBnAFQCuYADYQAPPwB8VflAgAPYBAB2AE17IAhipAYAdIZ0g8UAPxRgAJ0HQAXFABmWkbwjFO4aAGEqfIaISMDIA9CGWNu5EYVCxAHpmnmQAIn4CwmLi5KHhzq5RMfFmQA)